# Angular build fails in Unix systems because of src path for font-face?

Tags: css, angular, scss-mixins

I have below code in styles.scss build works fine in my windows system and when I deploy the code to devops repo build fails as it runs on linux machine

```
@font-face {
   font-family: "opensans-regular";
   src: url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf), url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.eot);
}
```

and I get below error

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleError: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
(Emitted value instead of an instance of Error) CssSyntaxError: /usr/src/app/src/styles.scss:14:12: Can't resolve 'assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf' in '/usr/src/app/src'

  12 | @font-face {
  13 |   font-family: "opensans-bold";
> 14 |   src: url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf), url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.eot);
     |   

     ^
```

Comment: Try starting the url of the font with a relative path, ../ or ./ and try quotes surrounding them, which is always good practice here

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be referring to two different fonts, OpenSans-bold and OpenSans-Regular.

Could it be the casing? Ive noticed bold is lowercase but Regular has uppercase first

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using relative path `assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf` which can not be resoved in linux. try using absoulte path from the `/src/...` and check if it works. As the error  `Can't resolve 'assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf' in '/usr/src/app/src'` shows it is trying to find `assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf` in this path: `'/usr/src/app/src'` which can not. Change the path and it will be ok.

Try something like this:

```
src: url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'OpenSans-bold';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/OpenSans-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```